# React-Native : Can we update value of Text dynamically using some unique id (without updating state variable)

Tags: react-native

Below code is useful to change the text value using state by re-rendering on press of button, but I want to change value of same Text using any id, is it possible?

**Sample Code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            value:'Text Value To Be Change Without Updating State'
        }
    }

     render(){
        return(
        <View style={{paddingTop: 20}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>{this.state.value}</Text>
            <Button title="Click" onPress={this.onPressButton }/>
        </View>
        );
    }
     onPressButton = () => {
            this.setState({
                value: "Can we change value of same text using some unique id, as happens in android using findViewById"
              })
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: see here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value

Comment: Hi Robbie, thanks for reply but the official example is using only state/props to change the data dynamically. I don't think that there is any way to change data without using state or props.

Comment: did you actually read the link I posted? It specifically does not use state and props, instead it calls the method `setNativeProps` and passes it an object `{text: ''}` with the text you'd like to set

Comment: Ohh, I just checked you link that is amazing actually, I don't know how I couldn't read the right post, I read but it was different last time, might be because of multiple tab, I had opened other one. Anyways I want to know one more thing can we change text colour or other property likewise you shared for text.

Comment: you can use `setNativeProps` to alter any style props, so `setNativeProps({ style: { color: 'red' } } )` would turn the color red

Comment: Thank you very much @Robbie. Its really helpful for me( or for a fresher in react native).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Robbie for your kind help, as you have provided me a link and explained, everything is working perfect. 
Sample code :

```
clearText = () => {
    this._textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TextInput
          ref={component => this._textInput = component}
          style={{height: 50, flex: 1, marginHorizontal: 20, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#ccc'}}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.clearText}>
          <Text>Clear text</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Reference link  - [Direct manipulation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-clear-textinput-value)